# Return modified model with Identity register form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the default form for registering a user with Identity, with slightly changed HTML only.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        // Do something with something here

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fornavn, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fornavn, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Etternavn, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Etternavn, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrer" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

It's using this register model, and I added a new prop which I just called "something".
How can I set the value of "something" in my view so that when the form is submitted I can access my "something" in the controller?

Thank you vey much

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public bool something { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Fornavn")]
    public string Fornavn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Etternavn")]
    public string Etternavn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Passord")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Gjenta passord")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would you like the property value to be selected by the user, using a check box perhaps?  Or would you like it to be hidden from view?

Comment: I would just like to set it to "true" in this spesific view, and then in my other view I would like it to be "false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting the value in your controller you can add a hidden field to your form using the HiddenFor() input extension:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.something)
```

or alternatively if you just want to hardcode the value. you can use:

```
@Html.Hidden("something", true)
```